# Can Azure WebJobs poll queues on demand?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-queues, azure-webjobssdk

I have a WebJob which gets triggered when a user uploads a file to the blob storage - it is triggered by a queue storage message which is created once the upload is complete.

Depending on the purpose of the file, it will post messages to other queues to trigger processing jobs.

Some of these jobs are time critical, and run relatively quickly. In one case the processing takes about three seconds, and the user is waiting for the result.

However, because the minimum queue polling interval is 2 seconds, the time the user must wait for the two WebJobs to be invoked is generally doubling their wait time.

I tried combining the two WebJobs into one, hoping that when the first handler posts a queue message the corresponding processing handler would be immediately triggered, but in fact it consistently waits two seconds before picking up the message.

My question is, is there a way for me to tell my WebJob to check the queue triggers immediately from within the same WebJob if I know there is a message waiting? Or even better configure it to immediately check the queue triggers if I post to a queue from inside the WebJob?

Or would switching to a service bus queue improve the responsiveness to new messages?

**Update**

In the docs about using blob triggers, it says:

> There is an exception for blobs that you create by using the Blob attribute. When the WebJobs SDK creates a new blob, it passes the new blob immediately to any matching BlobTrigger functions. Therefore if you have a chain of blob inputs and outputs, the SDK can process them efficiently. But if you want low latency running your blob processing functions for blobs that are created or updated by other means, we recommend using QueueTrigger rather than BlobTrigger.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/

However there is no mention of anything similar for queues. Meaning if you need *really* low latency in this scenario then blobs are the better than queues, which seems wrong.

**Update 2**

I ended up working around this by pulling the orchestrating code out of the first WebJob and into the service layer of the application and removing the WebJob.. it was fast running anyway so perhaps separating it into its own WebJob was an overkill. This means only the processing WebJob has to be triggered after the file upload.

Answer (score 2):

Currently 2 sec is the minimum time it will take for the SDK to poll for the new message. The SDK does an exponential back off polling so you can configure the MaxPollingInterval to be 2 sec always.
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

For more details please see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/#config

Comment: Yep, I also mentioned the 2 second minimum polling interval in my question.  I was hoping for something smarter, like what is implemented for blobs (see update on my question for more details).

Comment: It should happen for Queues as well. We do fast track notifications when the SDK sends a message.

Comment: Is it possible that fast tracking doesn't happen if the output queues are located using the IBinder interface?